# can I still use ubuntu 10.04 without security issue

Tags: ubuntu, security, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-unity

I really don't like unity interface, the problem is not its interface but it doesn't provide the options to customize it. (For example, no way to put the launchbar to bottom).

Hence I would like to use Ubuntu 10.04. But its support will expire in 2013 (April if I remember it correctly). Is there any security issue if I continue 10.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On April 2013 (Desktop) and April 2015 (Server) version 10.04 reaches its end of life, this means that no new updates, including security updates and critical fixes, will be made available for this version.

You can keep individual applications up to date, by adding their PPAs to your system's Software Sources. But that can result in unresolved dependencies.

If you don't like Unity, you can replace it with GNOME Shell or XFCE or any other desktop environment. It's really easy to install them (through Ubuntu Software Center) and they can exists parallel to Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the security patches for third party modules (expecially java) will still be updated via apt